# Retrofit interceptor error

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to add facebook access token into retrofit (2 beta 3) request, but the access token does not added.
I can add interceptor to retrofit 1.9 successfully but in retrofit 2 it has error, Is there any solution?

```
protected Retrofit getRestAdapter() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                    new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request original = chain.request();

                            String sessionId = getSessionId(); // get access token

                            // Request customization: add request headers
                            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                    .header("Cookie", sessionId)
                                    .method(original.method(), original.body());

                            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    })
            .build();

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://tbkha.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In retrofit retrofit 2.0 you add intercepter like this:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Check this link for details https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses

Similar questions:

[App crash on HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316028/app-crash-on-httplogginginterceptor)

[Retrofit2 HttpLoggingInterceptor Logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235565/retrofit2-httplogginginterceptor-logcat)